# Удалить числа после знака / включая сам знак

Tags: bash, sed, awk

День добрый, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Пишу скрипт на bash и скрипт получает параметр IP-адреса вида
`10.0.0.1/255.255.255.255`

Подскажите, как можно оставить только ту часть, где указан IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решается с помощью :

`echo '10.0.0.1/255.255.255.255' | awk -F"/" '{print $1}'`